# Count number of element in each col and save it in default dic

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to count number of occurrence for every item and save it in default dict based on its location in the list
for example :
if pass this list:

```
                   [[1, 2, 3, 4],<br />
                   [1, 3, 4, 2], <br />
                   [1, 2, 4, 3], <br />
                   [3, 4, 1, 2], <br />
                   [3, 4, 2, 1]]<br />
result : {1: [3, 0, 1, 1], 2: [0, 2, 1, 2], 3: [2, 1, 1, 1], 4: [0, 2, 2, 1]} ****Which is correct**.**
```

The issue happen when I pass 3 lists or 2. For example:

```
                   [1, 2, 4, 3], 
                   [3, 4, 1, 2],
the result: {1: [1, 0, 0, 1]}) **Which is wrong**
it should be {1: [1, 0, 1, 0], 2: [0, 1, 0, 1], 3: [1, 0, 0, 1], 4: [0, 1, 1, 0]}
Since one occurred 1 time in col1 and 1 time in col 3 1: [1, 0, 1, 0] etc
```

here is my code:

```
     j =1
      while j in range(len(votes_grid)):
          for i in range (len(votes_grid[0])):
              c = Counter((x[i] for x in votes_grid))
              if j in c:
                  columnTable[j].append(c[j])
              else:
                  columnTable[j].append(0)
            j+=1
```

I SOLVED IT AS FELLOW.

```
j = max(4, len(votes_grid))       
 while d in range(j+1):
            for i in range (len(votes_grid[0])):
                c = Counter((x[i] for x in votes_grid))
                if d in c:
                    columnTable[d].append(c[d])
                elif d in range(len(votes_grid[0])+1):
                    columnTable[d].append(0)
            d+=1
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what output you expect? My closest guess is that you want to count the number of times an element occurs in a column. So if there are four columns, you would have a list of four elements for each number `n`, and the `i`th entry in that list expresses how often `n` appeared in the `i`th column in the input lists.

Comment: Thank you for you response, I updated the excepted output in the wrong answer. Yes, you are correct I want to count number of times an element occurs in a col.

Answer (score 0):

You want to base your calculations on an item's location in the list, so the
**enumerate** function is your friend here: it lets you iterate over a list, while
at the same time giving you the index or position of the current object in the
list. Your code then becomes very simple:

```
# Initialize resulting dictionary with keys 1 to 4
result = {n+1: [0, 0, 0, 0] for n in range(4)}

for votes in votes_grid:
    for pos, j in enumerate(votes):
        result[j][pos] += 1
```